# Write multiple items to DynamoDB table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```py
datalist = [
    {'Business': 'Business A', 'Category': 'IT', 'Title': 'IT Manager'},
    {'Business': 'Business A', 'Category': 'Sourcing', 'Title': 'Sourcing Manager'}
]
```

I would like to upload to DynamoDB in the following format:

```
table.put_item(Item={
                    'Business':'Business A would go here',
                    'Category':'IT would go here',
                    'Title':'IT Manager would go here'
                    },
                    {
                    'Business':'Business B would go here',
                    'Category':'Sourcing would go here',
                    'Title':'Sourcing Manager would go here'
                    }
               )
```

I've tried converting the list of dicts to dict first and accessing the elements that way or trying to iterate through the Items parameter but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my DynamoDB structure, 3 columns (Business, Category, Title):

```
{
  "Business": {
    "S": "Business goes here"
  },
  "Category": {
    "S": "Category goes here"
  },
  "Title": {
    "S": "Title goes here"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the key structure of the table? Put Item can only upload 1 item per API call, you seem to be trying to upload two of them.

Comment: Thanks edited the OP with my desired structure. If there is a way I could upload "Company A" and "Company B" with the same call I would prefer that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `put_item` API call allows you to upload exactly one item, you're trying to upload two at the same time, this doesn't work.

You can batch multiple put items requests using boto3 to decrease the number of API calls. Here's an example adapted from the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#batch-writing):

```py
with table.batch_writer() as batch:

    for item in datalist:

        batch.put_item(
            Item=item
        )
```

This will automatically create the batch writes under the hood.

Comment: Thanks that was the way to go!